# Creating a new page after the build is done and the app is online (Next Js 13)

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a dynamic route in NextJS 13 where I fetch the slugs from a database.
Is it possible that after the build I don't have to rebuild the whole application if a new slug is added to the database?

I was able to update the content on a dynamic page using "export const revalidate=5", but I am unable to add new pages even if a new slug is inserted into the database (404 error when accessing the new route).

I want the page to be created automatically after the app is online when a new slug is added.

Comment: This should work nicely except that it might be cached or the setup is incorrect. Please provide how you create the page with the slug.